# How can taskflow be restarted after page reload?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have adf taskflow on page. Taskflow has 2 pages inside, page 1 is default page. When I open first page, go to second page and reload page in browser, I still see second page. What show I do to see page 1 after reload page in browser.

Answer (score 0):

That is the main principle behind ADF task flow navigation, principle that we all love and care about. And now, you want to change it!

Seriously, I don't know a simple way of doing it, but if I were to try something like this, I would use a pagePhaseListener:

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent phaseEvent) {
    if (!AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) 
    { 
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
        try {
            ec.redirect((request).getRequestURI());
            //you need to flag this redirect into the session, not to get an infinite loop.

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Again, I would be very careful with such approach, especially if you are using ADF Business Components.

Comment: I am using taskflow inside portlet. First step of taskflow is parameters initialization. So,  when webcenter portal put it's new parameters user see old,  because taskflow didn,t now about it and shows the same view of taskflow,  with old parameters.

Comment: I'll try to use your solution and will tell about the result.

Comment: I would suggest to redirect towards a static page (e.g. blank.html)
And in that page, to again redirect back to your portal from javascript ( body onload="document.location='www.yourportal.com'")